# Memory leaked or corrupted on Windows Service Config Get

Tags: delphi, winapi, memory-management

After 2 days wracking my brain,   I give up on fixing this problem  on my own.

I'm currently working on a service that needs to check the config of certain other services to decide if it can proceed with the rest of the program.

So far so good, it is working, but the clean up of the memory seems to be faulty. `GetMem()` and `FreeMem()` seem not to really give back the memory, and `New()` and `Dispose()` seem to break the memory allocation internally.

```
function tServiceStoppStart.GetServiceConfigStartTtype(sService: String): DWORD;
var
  schm, schs: SC_Handle;
  config: LPQUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG;
  pcbBytesNeeded: DWORD;
  sucessful: boolean;
begin
  try
    try
      begin
        sucessful := false;
        // open the service manager (defined in WinSvc)
        schm := OpenSCManager(nil, nil, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);

        if (schm > 0) then
        begin
          // grab the service handle
          schs := OpenService(schm, PChar(sService), SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS);
          if (schs > 0) then
          begin
            // get the byte count for the serviceconfig query
            //over the pcbBytesNeeded witchz is filled  with the right amount after 1. call
            QueryServiceConfig(schs, config, 0, pcbBytesNeeded);
            // 1. GetMem(config, pcbBytesNeeded);
            // 2. New(config); -> seems to corrupt   the memory allocation
            if QueryServiceConfig(schs, config, pcbBytesNeeded, pcbBytesNeeded) then
            begin
              Result := config.dwStartType;
              sucessful := True;
            end;
          end;
        end;
        CloseServiceHandle(schs);
      end;
    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        //
      end;
    end;
  finally
    begin;
     if sucessful then
     begin
       // seems not to free  the memory
       // 1. freeMem(config,pcbBytesNeeded)

       // 2. Dispose(config)  -> seems to corrupt the memory allocation
     end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

---

```
  {Set the new first free block}
  mov TSmallBlockPoolHeader[edx].FirstFreeBlock, ecx
  {Set the block header}  //  gets  accesviolation with  new  and dispose
  mov [eax - 4], edx
  {Is the chunk now full?}
  jz @RemoveSmallPool
```

by object create calls

I'm not that confident in my record handling in Delphi. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your error handling is incomplete.  You don't ensure that `CloseServiceHandle` is called for `schs` and you don't call it at all for `schm`.  Calling `new` on the same pointer you just called `GetMem` on is just wrong and doesn't make any sense...

Comment: @j...  schm is   the service manager    not  a  service  iam unsure    if  that  works  ;/   and the  record  type  is   pretty  much  predefinden  by  the function QueryServiceConfig(hService: SC_HANDLE;
  lpServiceConfig: LPQUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG; cbBufSize: DWORD;
  var pcbBytesNeeded: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall;    i am unsure     how   to  get  there  an own record type in  beween

Comment: [The returned handle ... can be closed by calling the CloseServiceHandle function.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-openscmanagerw)

Comment: it is either   (getmen+ freeMem) or (new + dispose) i  do not mix them so  far  as i know  that  mackes problems      i only  written  both in the   code aas  example  what i tried

Comment: Looks  like it got fixed  thoug  the   closing  of  the   manager   proably   got    meomry leak  from  build  up  by   manager  opening spam  thx  J...   for  the cue  for the   close

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it got fixed thoug the closing of the manager proably got meomry leak from build up by manager opening spam thx J... for the cue for the close